# How to combine min-width and max-width in one media query

Tags: css

This media query is not working as I expected it to.

What I want to do is hide an element if the window is below 544px, and also hide it if it is above 767px.  So it will only be visible while the window is between 544px and 767px.

```
@media (max-width: 544px) and (min-width: 767px) {
    .show-sm-only {
        display: none !important;
    }
 }
```

It seems that they work separately, but not together.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can combine two media queries in one, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 544px), (min-width: 767px) {
.show-sm-only {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

**EDIT** This will hide `.show-sm-only` on screen smaller than (max-width) 544px and on screen bigger than (min-width) 767px.

Answer (score 20):

If you want a media query that is applied when BOTH conditions are true (which I think is what you're looking for here), use another `and`. Here it's hidden by default, and only visible when between 544px to 767px.

```
.my-element {
  display: none;

  @media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I came here for! Good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You want this, your rules are the wrong way round. Right now you're saying it must be smaller than (max-width) 544px, but bigger than (min-width) 767px, which is impossible. See below how they are the other way round.

**EDIT** As per the comments. To do `or` (instead of `and`, which for your situation is impossible), separate with a comma:

```
@media (max-width: 544px), (min-width: 767px) {
    .show-sm-only {
        display: none !important;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, and that does the opposite of what I want: It hides it between 544px and 767.

Comment: I see! Misinterpretted the question. Apologies.

Comment: @GregGum Actually this still applies. Remember, **both** rules must be true (hence `and` in the middle). You need a comma to separate OR rules.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to find how to do an "or" but I didn't find anything in the docs.